# How to decode a static value in Elm

Tags: json, decode, elm

Using `Json.decode`  is it possible to decode a static value, say The Json doesn't contain a value, but I want the local type alias to have more data that has a default. How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to do this,

using `Decode.succeeded`

```
import Json.Decode as Decode

-- snip

Decode.map2 Item
    (Decode.field "title" Decode.string)
    (Decode.succeed 0)
```

(where `Item` is an arbitrary `type alias`)

---

Or using a closure

```
Decode.map (\name -> {name = name, age = 42} ) (Decode.field "name" Decode.string)
```